# Using .update on defaultdict with missing keys

Tags: python, dictionary, defaultdict

I need to create a dict structured like this:

```
{'top':
    {'left':{
         00: 'value_00',
         01: 'value_01',
         ...},
    'right':{
         00: 'value_00',
         01: 'value_01',
         ...}}
'bottom':
    {'left':{
         00: 'value_00',
         01: 'value_01',
         ...}
    'right':{
         00: 'value_00',
         01: 'value_01',
         ...}}
}
```

where:

- the number of values (value_00, ...) can change between different keys;
- I always have the 'top' and 'bottom' entries, but some times only one between 'left' and 'right'

So, I tried using a defaultdict to avoid missing keys errors, and adding the id: value_id pairs with the .update() method, something like this (this is a simplified version, as I said the number of values/fields can vary):

```
from collections import defaultdict

res = defaultdict(dict)
ids_list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
values_list = ['value_00', 'value_01', 'value_02', 'value_03', 'value_04', 'value_05', 'value_06']

for vert_pos in ['top', 'bottom']:
    for hor_pos in ['left', 'right']:
        for ID, val in zip (ids_list, values_list):
            res[vert_pos][hor_pos].update({ID: val})

print(res)
```

But I'm getting the error:

```
res[vert_pos][hor_pos].update({ID: val})
KeyError: 'left'
```

so, in spite of using a defaultdict, it seems the update() method still requires the key to exist...if I tried to just write something, like:

```
res[vert_pos][hor_pos] = {ID: val}
```

it works, even though I end up just with the last (ID: value) pair.

```
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {'top': {'right': {6: 'value_06'}}, 'bottom': {'right': {6: 'value_06'}}})
```

I also tried using:

```
res.update({vert_pos: {hor_pos: {id: val}}})
```

but, once again, I end up with only the last (ID: value).

Comment: `defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(dict))`?

Comment: Generally, you don't need [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) and bunch of loops there, just apply [`deepcopy()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy): `d = dict(zip(ids_list, values_list)) ; d = {"left": d, "right": d.copy()} ; res = {"top": d, "bottom": deepcopy(d)}`